# The tail is replaced instead of append

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I have a method called `public void insertAfterSecondOccurrence(T e1, T e2)` that would insert an integer after the second occurrence of another integer. However my problem is that if the integer inserted is before the last integer in the list, the method would just replace the tail with the inserted integer instead of appending it.

Here is the method code :

```java
public void insertAfterSecondOccurrence(T e1, T e2) {   
    // insert e1 after the second occurence of e2

    if(isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Error the list is empty.");
    }

    SLLNode<T> p = head;
    int count = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < size(); i++) {
        if(p.info.equals(e2)) {
            count++;
        }
        p = p.next;
    }

    if(count <= 1) {
        System.out.println("Error there is no sec");
    }

    SLLNode<T> p2 = head;
    SLLNode<T> p3 = head;
    SLLNode<T> pred =head;
    SLLNode<T> tmp = new SLLNode<T>(e1);
    int count2 = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < size(); i++) {
        if(p2.info.equals(e2)) {
            pred = p2.next;
            p3 = p2;
            count2++;
        }
        if(count2 == 2) {
            break;
        }
        p2 = p2.next;
    }

    pred.next = pred;
    pred = pred.next;
    p3.next = tmp;
}
```

I tried replacing the last 3 lines with :

```java
tail.next = tail;
tail = tail.next;
p3.next = tmp;
```

But it didn't work. Here is an example of how it should be, this is the original array `[ 7 5 3 50 7 9 ]`, after calling the method it should be `[ 7 5 3 50 7 30 9 ]`, what i keep getting is `[ 7 5 3 50 7 30 ]`.

I would appreciate if you give me basic responses this is my first time using the website so I'm not familiar with the terms/slang in this website.

Comment: Can you please add some more code to make it a [mre] ? Hard to tell what's going on without the code to reproduce your test results.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the last 3 lines with this code :
p3.next = tmp;
tmp.next = pred;

And solved my problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).